# Dynamically selecting option in dropdown menu using jquery/javascript only working sometimes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I am currently trying to populate a dropdown menu and dynamically selecting one of the options using jquery/javascript, but am running into a problem with it setting the select state consistently.

Modal Window:

```
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form id="editForm">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit User: <strong class="fullname"></strong></h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <input type="hidden" class="id" name="id">
            <div class="row form-group">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group bmd-form-group is-filled">
                  <label class="bmd-label-floating" for="roles">Site Role</label>
                  <!--Dropdown to be populated dynamically -->
                  <select class="form-control bmd-form-group is-filled roles" data-style="btn btn-link" id="edit_roles" name="roles"></select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--Other inputs removed for clarity -->
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="material-icons">check</i> Update</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
//edit
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function(){
  
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  
  getRoles("edit");
  
  getDetails(id);
  
  $('#edit').modal('show');
});

$('#editForm').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var editform = $(this).serialize();
  $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'controllers/edit.php',
    data: editform,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
      if(response.error){
        //Generate popup notification
        $.notify({
          message: response.message
        },{
          type: 'warning'
        });
        
      }
      else{
        //Generate popup notification
        $.notify({
          message: response.message
        },{
          type: 'success'
        });
        
        
        fetch();
      }
      $('#edit').modal('hide');
    }
  });
});
//



function fetch(){
  $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'controllers/fetch.php',
    success: function(response){
      $('#tbody').html(response);
    }
  });
}

function getDetails(id){
  $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'controllers/fetch_row.php',
    data: {id:id},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
      //alert(JSON.stringify(response));
      if(response.error){
        $('#edit').modal('hide');
        $('#delete').modal('hide');
        $('#alert').show();
        $('#alert_message').html(response.message);
      }
      else{
        // Start populating the modal window with the user's details
        
        //*******For some reason this only works sporadically*******
        $('#edit_roles').val(response.data.u_rolecode);
        //$('.roles option[value=' + response.data.u_rolecode + ']').attr('selected','selected');
        
        $('.id').val(response.data.u_userid)
        $('.username').val(response.data.u_username);
        $('.password').val(response.data.u_password);
        $('.firstname').val(response.data.u_firstname);
        $('.lastname').val(response.data.u_lastname);
        $('.email').val(response.data.u_email);
        $('.jobtitle').val(response.data.u_jobtitle);
        $('.active').val(response.data.u_is_active);
        $('.created').val(response.data.u_create_at);
        $('.fullname').html(response.data.u_firstname + ' ' + response.data.u_lastname);
      }
    }
  });
}


function getRoles(prefix){
  $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'controllers/fetch_roles.php',
    success: function(response){
      $('#' + prefix +'_roles').html("<option value='0'>- Select -</option>" + response);
    }
  });
}
```

When a person tries to edit a user's details, a modal window is populated with the user's current details, a dropdown is populated with the list of all site roles available, and the user's specific site role is selected dynamically.

From what I can see at least, all requests to the database are successful - the user's data is all returned and displayed correctly, and the list of all site roles available is also returned and populated correctly.

However, actually setting a selected state for the user's specific role within that dropdown list seems to function sporadically. I've tried setting the state by ID and by classname, with the same hit and miss result each time.

I have noticed that I have a better chance of 'forcing' this to happen by opening and closing the modal edit window quickly, but it also still happens as part of what I would consider to be non extreme regular usage.

$('#edit_roles').val(response.data.u_rolecode);
//$('.roles option[value=' + response.data.u_rolecode + ']').attr('selected','selected');

**Output #1: Working**

[image: Modal window with 'Site Role' dropdown populated, and user's role already selected]

[image: HTML: 'selected' attribute set successfully]

**Output #2: Not Working**

[image: Modal window with 'Site Role' dropdown populated but user's role not selected]

[image: Output: 'selected' attribute not set]

(It *is* a dropdown, despite bootstrap making it appear not so.)

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: what does `response.data.u_rolecode` have are values in uppercase can you show output of that ?

Comment: and you better provide some jdFiddle or CodePen so we can easily re-produce the problem

Comment: There is not much detail to work with but usually in these cases, the problem is in the order of how code is executed. Incorrect order of loading scripts might also be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `getRoles` and `getDetails` are both asynchronous operations, meaning there's no assurance of which one will finish operation first.

Possible solutions:

1. Make `getRoles` ajax request a synchronous call
2. Call `getDetails` within `getRoles` ajax success condition (this could be achieved through `callback` as well)

Edit: I would personally go for 2nd option since it doesn't block/freeze the page.

Comment: Thank you. I suspected it was to do with the operations being asynchronous, however I didn't have the knowledge to set that right. 

Coupled with the example given by @Thomson Mixab above, I tried both of your suggestions. As expected, both of the above suggestions remedied the issue.

Comment: @user6790086 I would personally go for 2nd option

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the getDetails page make synchronous call to return response data.

```
function getDetails(id){
  $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'controllers/fetch_row.php',
    async: false,          // ***** you need to make synchonous call 
    data: {id:id},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
      //alert(JSON.stringify(response));
      if(response.error){
        $('#edit').modal('hide');
        $('#delete').modal('hide');
        $('#alert').show();
        $('#alert_message').html(response.message);
      }
      else{
        // Start populating the modal window with the user's details
        
        //*******For some reason this only works sporadically*******
        $('#edit_roles').val(response.data.u_rolecode);
        //$('.roles option[value=' + response.data.u_rolecode + ']').attr('selected','selected');
        
        $('.id').val(response.data.u_userid)
        $('.username').val(response.data.u_username);
        $('.password').val(response.data.u_password);
        $('.firstname').val(response.data.u_firstname);
        $('.lastname').val(response.data.u_lastname);
        $('.email').val(response.data.u_email);
        $('.jobtitle').val(response.data.u_jobtitle);
        $('.active').val(response.data.u_is_active);
        $('.created').val(response.data.u_create_at);
        $('.fullname').html(response.data.u_firstname + ' ' + response.data.u_lastname);
      }
    }
  });
}
```